# Login screen on Ubuntu fails to go into full screen or to fill window

Tags: virtualbox, login-screen, display-resolution

The login screen on Ubuntu fails to go into full screen or to fill window.

However, when logging-in to user accounts, the screen does go full.

I have already installed Guest Additions correctly and i use the Auto-resize Guest Display as shown at the image below.

That is maybe happening because of the console resolution (800x600).

But i don't want to make it static, but to make it resizable, by adjusting the host's window size.

I [image: Screenshot of login screen as window]

Comment: The issue you face is not necessarily an issue with Ubuntu, but rather an apparent issue with VirtualBox on Windows interacting with the Guest Additions.  This is not really on topic here as a result.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic -y` and then restart your VM and then install Guest Additions again and then restart. It should work fine after that.

Comment: @Alex it worked. can you post it as asnwer to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install Virtual Machine's Guest Additions you have to run:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic -y
```

Once you have done that restart the VM and then once it boots back up go to **Selecting Devices -> Install Guest Additions** and then restart the VM once more. After that it should work perfectly fine.